# Scan column names, pick the ones containing specific text, and run functions on them (SUM, MAX etc)

Tags: google-sheets, average, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

In Google Sheets, I have a spreadsheet that looks like this

```
A1    A2    A3    B1    B2    B3    C1    C2    C3
55    23    21    15    18    15    61    51    51
51    15    15    81    98    13    51    74    65
15    87    89    99    32    72    15    58    51
18    64    15    81    32    15    81    78    98
87    81    32    51    15    35    15    81    12
```

I want to create a separate sheet that will find the sum/max/average/min of all the "A" named columns.

Is there a way to make a function in a cell that will (lets' pick one for now) average all the cells in the same row whose column names match a certain text pattern (e.g. "A*")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
 "sum",         SUM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TO_TEXT(A1:I)), 
 "where Col1 contains 'A'", 0)), "where Col1 !='' offset 1", 0)*1);
 "max",         MAX(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TO_TEXT(A1:I)), 
 "where Col1 contains 'A'", 0)), "where Col1 !='' offset 1", 0)*1);
 "average", AVERAGE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TO_TEXT(A1:I)), 
 "where Col1 contains 'A'", 0)), "where Col1 !='' offset 1", 0)*1);
 "min",         MIN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TO_TEXT(A1:I)), 
 "where Col1 contains 'A'", 0)), "where Col1 !='' offset 1", 0)*1)})
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TO_TEXT(Raw!$A1:$AR)), 
 "where Col1 contains '"&REGEXEXTRACT(C1, ".")&"'", 0)), 
 "where Col1 !='' offset 1", 0)*1), 
 "select "&REGEXREPLACE(JOIN( , IF(LEN(Raw!$C2:$C),
 "max(Col"&ROW(Raw!$C2:$C)-ROW(Raw!$C2)+1&"),", )), ".\z", "")&"")),
 "select Col2"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this works indeed.

How would you make it work in another sheet? E.g. if one sheet was like this and you wanted in another sheet to "Scan" the first sheet and get the AVERAGE (or MAX etc) of all the columns that had "A" as their starting letter?

https://imgur.com/a/cT5A1dI

Comment: Thank you, there you go. It's the first two sheets.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RiLoa_NVfOdwfrh-qsG2LQmjkM1wUb5sfFj8TYCmrKk/edit#gid=581562525

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array formula like this:

```
ArrayFormula(average(if(left(A1:I1,1)="A",A2:I)))
```

[image]

Or if preferred use pattern matching for more flexibility:

```
=ArrayFormula(average(if(regexmatch(A1:I1,"^A"),A2:I)))
```

(case sensitive).